# mongo/mongoose query to find field removing space

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Can we create a mongoose query to return a result of a specific field data without space in between?

for example: 
series 'KA 04 A' and 'KA04A' is same. i want to make a check while adding a new series if the new series is already exist in my mongodb thru mongoose.

Currently my series field have space in between 
the current code of my mongoose is:

```
seriesModel.find({series_name:req.body.seriesName.toUpperCase(), status:'active'}, function(err, data){
        if(err){

            logger.info(err);
            return false;
        }
        else if(data.length){

            return res.json({error:true,message:'Series name already exists.'});
        }
```

how can i return field data from db without space. so that i can make a check if the same series exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would standardize your `series_name` field *before* saving the record, using a custom hook that strips out whitespace.

That being said, you can use a regular expression in your query. For example, you can search for uppercase/lowercase variations on the word "mongoose" as follows:

```
model.findOne({name: /mongoose/i}, fn(){...});
```

One way to solve your problem would be to take your string, split it into individual characters, and then inject the whitespace pattern `\s` between all the characters (I am assuming there is no leading or trailing whitespace in this field):

```
"^" + "KA04A".split("").join("\\s*") + "$" // "^K\s*A\s*0\s*4\s*A$"
```

(The start `^` and end `$` are necessary so that we do not get false positives on e.g. "xKA04Ax")

Next, you would need to convert this string into the regex format ( `/^K\s*A\s*0\s*4\s*A$/`) and plug it into your query:

```
model.findOne({name: new RegExp("^K\\s*A\\s*0\\s*4\\s*A$")}, fn(){...});
```

Major Caveat: you will need to be super careful that your original string only contains `a-zA-Z0-9` and whitespace. It cannot contain anything that could be mistaken as a regex pattern without first escaping those characters (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript) for more on this approach).